# Equal Column Heights

Tags: html, css

I want the east and west divs to extend down to match the height of the center div... possible?

Thanks so much.

```
.con{
padding-left: 22px;
padding-right: 22px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.col{
position: relative;
float: left;
}

.west{
width: 7px;
right: 22px; 
margin-left: -100%;
background: url(http://www.example.com/west.png) repeat-y;
padding: 0 0 0 15;
}

.east{
width: 7px;
margin-right: -22px;
background: url(http://www.example.com/east.png) repeat-y;
padding: 0 15 0 0;
}

.center{
width: 100%;
}


<div class="con">
  <div class="center col">
   Test Text<br/>
   Test Text<br/>
   Test Text<br/>
   Test Text<br/>
  </div>
  <div class="west col">
 </div>
 <div class="east col">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780325/both-columns-same-height-as-deepest-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with what's done here for CSS-only:
[HTML/CSS: Making two floating divs the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height/)

Or use JavaScript layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I used this jQuery solution and it works great...

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$(".col").each(function(){
  maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
}).height(maxHeight);​
```

Just FYI for others looking. Trying to css it tho.