# How can I apply equal heights to floating DIVs in this case?

Tags: javascript, css

I am dynamically parsing DIVs which are floating left to each other in two columns. The problem now that if any DIV has more content/height than the other, the page looks messy because there's no clearing for the floats.

I am asking how can I make all DIVs have the same height? (All DIVS have a specific class like this .cat-widget) I just want them to be same-height to float without problem and line-up perfectly on page.

Any suggestions, best practice to do this please let me know.

Comment: Can't you set an explicit height for a class to be applied to the divs?

Comment: I can't. The content is dynamic and variable. else, I could just have fixed height set for the given class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works wonderfully:

```
<div style='display:table'>
  <div style='display:table-row'>
    <div style='display:table-cell'>..content..</div>
    <div style='display:table-cell'>..content..</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/steve/ua32f/) and tutorial [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200405/equal_height_boxes_with_css/).  Just tested working in FF 3.6, IE8, Chrome 7, and Safari $.

Comment: You might as well be using a table though ;)

Answer (score 1):

This question useful? [Both columns same height as deepest column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780325/both-columns-same-height-as-deepest-column)

Answer (score 1):

A Javascript solution you could fall back on is:

```
// get both heights
var heightFirst   = document.getElementById('....').offsetHeight;
var heightSecond  = document.getElementById('....').offsetHeight;

// find largest
var maxHeight = Math.max(heightFirst, heightSecond);

// set both to largest
document.getElementById('....').style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
document.getElementById('....').style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
```

There are also a few CSS solutions detailed here:
http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 0):

apply `height` and `overflow:hidden` to to all divs

Comment: The content is dynamic so I can't set fixed height. that's why

Answer (score 0):

I actually use, when needed:

```
<div class="somename" style="min-height: 300px;">
```

Comment: The content is dynamic, I can't know for sure what the user will put in the widget, the height is variable. :(